# XAML, Pivot: how to bind a PivotHeader property inside PivotHeader definition?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

I edited the default Pivot Header Item Style to change its foreground property when a user changes the selected pivot item to a color of mine (See VisualState Selected, I didn't pasted everything):

```
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
        <!-- ... -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <!-- ... -->
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                     <!-- ... -->
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <!-- ... -->
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                    <!-- ... -->
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                 <!-- ... -->
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

If my PivotItem.Header is defined as a TextBlock, the foreground changes as expected.

Now I want the same with Ellipse. The problem is that Ellipse doesn't have a foreground property. I thought I maybe have to bind the fill brush to the foreground brush, but I don't know how to do it.

```
 <Pivot Grid.Row="1">

    <PivotItem x:Name="Test">

        <PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid>

                <Ellipse
                         Fill="{How to bind PivotItemHeader Foreground?}"
                         Width="20" Height="20" />
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem.Header>

    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem x:Name="Test2">

        <PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid>

                <Ellipse
                         Fill="{How to bind PivotItemHeader Foreground?}"
                         Width="20" Height="20" />
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem.Header>

    </PivotItem>

</Pivot>
```

I tried with no success:

```
Fill="{Binding ElementName=Test, Path=HeaderItem.Foreground}"
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I can't get your point. `HeaderItem` is not supported in UWP, and `PivotItem.Header` doesn't have a `Foreground`  property. Or are you trying to do this: `<PivotItem x:Name="Test" Foreground="Pink">
    <PivotItem.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding ElementName=Test, Path=Foreground}" Width="20" Height="20" />
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem.Header>
</PivotItem>
`?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Tried to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Template, you change the `Foreground` of `ContentPresenter` in the `Selected` VisualState. So I assume that you want to make a `Ellipse` as header of each item, and change the color of these ellipses when you select each item.

To do this, you can use your modified template with `Pivot.HeaderTemplate` and use the [RelativeSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) property like this:

```
<Pivot Grid.Row="1">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Foreground}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <PivotItem>
        <TextBlock Text="11111" />
    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem>
        <TextBlock Text="22222" />
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Here the `DataTemplate` is applied to the `ContentPresenter` in your modified template, so we can use [TemplatedParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.relativesourcemode) to bind the `Ellipse` to its `Parent`.

Or here is another method, you can modify your template like this:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding ElementName=ContentPresenter, Path=Foreground}" />
</ContentPresenter>
```

and meanwhile use `Pivot` control like this:

```
<Pivot Grid.Row="1">
    <PivotItem>
        <TextBlock Text="11111" />
    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem>
        <TextBlock Text="22222" />
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Just be aware that your "change color" part of the template target the `ContentPresenter`, not a `HeaderItem`, you can see this `ContentPresenter` with the help of `LiveVisual Tree`.